# Ubuntu 12.04 not recognising my new wireless "super hub"

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, and this is the first time I've reached out and asked for help.  Please let me know if you need any more information.

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) replacing Ubuntu 10.10 (32-bit) on my Samsung n150plus netbook last week.

Just before I did the install, we had a new router fitted with a new network and password etc.

My netbook worked fine with this router when it was using 10.10. But immediately after I installed 12.04, the SSID for that network was no longer detected. It does not come up in the list of available wireless networks.

However, if I use a wireless USB adapter/stick, it connects fine. The netbook's internal wifi also works when used with other wireless networks. But not with this one router.

Please let me know if I can give any more information that would help to solve the problem.

---

#### Some other details copied from comments

- The router is a Virgin Media Super Hub (VMSH) made by Netgear.
- My [**Samsung N150plus**](http://www.samsung.com/levant/consumer/computers-peripherals/laptops/netbook/NP-N150-JP06JO-spec) connects with no problem to other wifi networks. I appear to only have problems with this router.
- I tried using a friend's Mac and it had no problem establishing a wifi connection to this router.

Comment: Do any other wireless routers/networks work correctly? Is the router displayed if you boot the Live CD or USB of an earlier Ubuntu release? Have you tried to manually add the router using "Edit Connections" in the network icon's menu? (Image in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/132475/52923) provides an example of this menu.)

Comment: thanks John.  Other networks work fine.  This network I want to use doesn't show up on my list of wireless networks.  The router worked fine on my 32 bit Ubuntu 10:10.  I forgot to mention that this is the 64 bit ubuntu 12.04.  I don't know if that makes any difference..  I did try to add the router manually, including the ssid.  I wasn't sure what else to add, and this didnt make any difference.

Comment: Can other computers (or operating systems) see the `SSID` of this network and connect to it? Just trying to rule out the possibility of a router problem coincident with your install of 12.04.

Comment: yes, my girlfriend's mac has no problem connecting to that particular network.  It is recognised and can be connected to

Comment: So what is different between routers/networks where your netbook wi-fi works and this one?

Comment: The difference is that they are recognised and I can connect to them with no problem.

Comment: Uh-huh. `<grin/>` Seriously, I'm out of guesses. You have access to the devices whereas I do not even know a single model number or even a manufacturer name. All I can suggest at the moment is look for a way the routers differ. For example, something like the new one is 802.11n while the others are all 802.11g. (I assume that's not true though, is it?)

Comment: Thanks so much anyway John.  How would I find the difference? The serial number is 2ha31buk372a5, but it didn't help me find the model.  I know its by netgear.  I'll look into it, maybe I could write to virgin and ask for the model of the router.

Comment: This router is hardware provided your Internet Service Provider (ISP)? Can anyone login to it with a browser and review its settings? Perhaps you could take a picture of the router and add it to your question?

Comment: i dont have a camera, what kind of information would be helpful to know?  There is a lot of information.  I think that its 802.11n, but the broadcom driver that I have with ubuntu says that it works for that.

Comment: It might help to know the manufacturer and a model number. Basically   any information that uniquely identifies the router in a search for information with Google and/or on the manufacturer's web site.

Comment: its a virgin media super hub, made by netgear.  Will the serial number help, or is there something else I should look out for?

Comment: OK, it seems easy to find their support online. Does [**this website**](http://bit.ly/Ji5O2U) match your "Virgin Media" and router? Does [**this image**](http://www.virginmedia.com/images/label_black.gif) match the label on your router? If you want to work on this it would probably best be done through chat. Would that work for you? What timezone are you in? Are you allowed to sign on to router so we can examine its settings? Oh, yeah, are you *broadband* or *national*? (Don't think it matters much, but I was curious. :)

Comment: I took the liberty of attempting to fold in a few key points from the comments. I also edited the question a bit. Please look it over and make sure I did *NOT* say anything wrong. If I did please edit and correct it!! Please also check this link I used for the [Samsung N150plus](http://www.samsung.com/levant/consumer/computers-peripherals/laptops/netbook/NP-N150-JP06JO-spec) to verify that this **really is** your netbook. Do you still have windows 7 installed on the netbook? If so what happens when you use windows?

Comment: Thanks so much John, sorry that its taken me so long to get back to you.  Yes, all of the information you have is correct.  I'm pretty sure its broadband, as I dont know what national is.  My friend had the same problem and he said that getting another broadcom driver helped to solve it.  What do you reckon?  I'm in the UK and would be happy to skype/chat at a good time for you.  Many thanks for all your help and time, its really appreciated :)

Comment: If your friend has exactly the same computer or at least exactly the same wireless chipset, then maybe it's worth a try. Otherwise I would have my doubts. I'll try to put together a list of commands you could run which might help by providing more information about your setup. It'll probably take me a day or two though. It would be something like along the lines of this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WirelessTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: hi john, this would be great.  I tried the method he used, and it didnt work.  Should I post the commands to you, or on this forum, will there be a lot of text?  And should I use the commands in the link or wait for yours.  Thanks so much for this mate, I owe you a pint :)

Comment: It's taking me longer to put together so it'll be another day (or two). The output will be pretty long. I was thinking it should be directed into a file and then the file copied to a pastebin, such as http://pastebin.ubuntu.com, and you could add the URL to your question so others could view the data. Can't promise it will lead anywhere, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Hi John, my friend asked around some forums, and someone suggested checking the wireless channel that it was on.  Apparently some laptops/netbooks will only recognise channels 1-11, and this was on channel 13!  So we changed the channel to 1 and now it works!  This explains why the new router changed everything, because the last router must have been set to a lower number.  Thanks so much for all of your time and help John, its much appreciated mate.

Comment: I'm just glad you got it fixed. It unlikely that I ever would have thought that the router would be on channel 13. Most routers have an option to automagically pick the channel. I would suggest trying that to minimize possible interference from other nearby routers. Another approach is to see what channels other nearby routers are using and just get as far away from that as you can while still staying between 1 and 11. Would you please create an answer with your final solution and then mark it as the "best solution".

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade kernel and then see the results. Ubuntu 12.04 comes with kernel 3.2. I have upgraded to 3.4 kernel.

Comment: You may want to edit this answer to explain some of the potential dangers in upgrading the kernel to 3.4 (so people who follow this answer are prepared), explain how to upgrade it (or link to something that does), and explain as best you can why upgrading it will help in this situation.